# How to get a content (text and images) from the website (WordPress)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, ios9

I try to create an application in SWIFT, which is able to show content (text and images only) in this application. Problem is, that I know how to display full body of web page, but I don't know how I can get the content only and display in in text area. Is anybody here, who have an idea how to solve my problem?

That's all what I have:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL (string: "http://dookolakotatv.pl")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webWiev.loadRequest(request)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the request and get the HTML code back. Then you would have to use different parsing techniques to extract the images and text out.

Example :

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let url = NSURL (string: "http://dookolakotatv.pl")
let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response:NSURLResponse!, 
error: NSError!) -> Void in
     let html = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
     //Then extract the info you want from the HTML
})

dataTask.resume() //Will execute asynchronously the previous task
```

Comment: Thank you very much for it, but I don't know how to extract this part of code of HTML which I need. Can I count on some advice in this case?